# HTML - Return Total Money value in defined format

Tags: javascript, html

I've got everything else working in this contact form invoice but I am not able to make this script to return total money value in the following format: 00.00

I have added the `.tofixed(2)` in several places and have only managed to make it return .00 when it should be .60.

I am a self-learner so I am struggling to figure it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.

Comment: How do you expect summing integers to produce fractions?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 method in JavaScript that deals with parsing of number from string:

- [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

When dealing with numbers that has decimal points, you would need to use `parseFloat` instead so the decimal part isn't discarded.

How `parseInt()` works is, it will try to match as many valid characters as possible (following the `radix` passed in the second argument, usually default to `10` except special case*):

```js
parseInt('123.45'); // 123
parseInt('12abc'); // 12
```

This is why we need `parseFloat()` to solve the first scenario:

```js
parseFloat('123.45'); // 123.45
parseFloat('12abc'); // 12
```

(Unlike `parseInt()`, it doesn't accept a `radix` second argument and can only be base of 10)

---

Solution based on your case:

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to convert the above script to use this.

Comment: Hi @dragonzladi, updated to include the solution based on your case.

Comment: My Hero!!!! Thank you. Ive been fighting this way to long.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can us `totalValue.toLocaleString()` function which will format your target string according to the required currency format.

```
<p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>

<script>
  const totalValue= 1234.56; // You can add your logic of incrementing total value here
  const formatTotal = totalValue.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'EUR'
  });
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = formatTotal;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the number is not converted to float until it doesn't have a decimal value greater than 0 even if we use pasrseFloat() on that.

For a decimal number, **parseInt()** returns us a whole number and on the other hand, **parseFloat()** provides the results with the decimal value.

For example,

```js
let a = 5;
console.log(parseFloat(a)); //returns 5 even when we have parsed it to float.
console.log(parseFloat(a)); //returns 5, a whole number.

let b = 5.0;
console.log(parseFloat(b)); //still returns 5 even though we have 0 as a decimal point.

let c = 5.1;
console.log(parseFloat(c)); //now returns 5.1 as we have a decimal point greater than zero.

console.log(parseInt(c)); //returns 5, and converts the decimal number to the whole number.
```

This is where a formatter comes into play i.e. **toFixed()** which formats the number up to decimal points entered and returns it as a string.

The solution for your code is to change the parseInt to parseFloat while calculating and formatting it with toFixed wherever you need to display it.

```
function findTotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
```

}